# How construct simulations using the Markov chain in R or Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

help please

I need to simulate a set of random numbers which are belongs to the polulation of unknown distribution. 
 still I'm not sure whether I should use a transition matrix to do the simulation?

I have already written a R code to do the simulation but it didn't work .

Please let me know your thoughts about how to define a transition matrix for this problem.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 probs <- c(0.35,0.25, 0.45) 
 x <- rep(10,3) 

while (min(x) > 0){
   w <- sample(1:3,1,replace = T, prob = probs)
   x[w] <- x[w] + 3
   x <- x - 1
}
x
```

Comment: thank you very much :D :D wow this code is great